# CountDown timer object using the wrong 'this' value

Tags: javascript, oop, timer

I am having trouble with making a counter Object. What I want it to do is to start a timer with a newly created object. The timer does not start unless the object variables are set as global variables. Can someone take a look at this and help me out?

Here is the code:

```
function Clock(timeInMinutes){
    this.seconds = timeInMinutes * 60;
    this.current = 0;
}

Clock.prototype = {
    constructor: Clock,
    start: function(){
        function increase(){
            if(this.current <= this.seconds){
                console.log(this.current);
                this.current++;
            }
        }
        setInterval(increase,1000);
    }
};
```

When I enter this code nothing happens:

```
var clock = new Clock(1);
clock.start();
```

Things only happen when i do this:

```
this.current = 0;
this.seconds = 60;
```

Why is the 'this' value inside the start function not working as I want it do be?

Comment: Try `setInterval(increase.bind(this),1000);`. MDN has an explanation of [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you explain how this works? When the increase function is called from the newly created object, isn't the 'this' value bound to the object.

Comment: No it isn't. The value of `this` within a function depends on how that function is called. Using "dot" notation like `clock.start()` means that within `start()` the `this` value is `clock`, but `increase()` isn't called like that. Read the page I linked to (unfortunately it's been edited a few times and isn't as clear as it used to be, but it covers the basics).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Clock.prototype = {
    constructor: Clock,
    start: function(){
        var that = this;
        function increase(){
            if(that.current <= that.seconds){
                console.log(that.current);
                that.current++;
            }
        }
        setInterval(increase,1000);
    }
};
```

http://jsbin.com/nasuyuyove/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Close...need to move the `that` declaration to outside `increase()`. Would be nice to explain why that is necessary in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

**Try with :** `var that=this;` `start` function & inside another one function also there.Prototype only with `start` function. Inside function is different one.so declare the prototype function of `that= this` .Then call the `that`.its act as the prototype `this`

```js
function Clock(timeInMinutes){
    this.seconds = timeInMinutes * 60;
    this.current = 0;
}

Clock.prototype = {
    
    constructor: Clock,
   start: function(){
     var that=this;
        function increase(){
            if(that.current <= that.seconds){
                console.log(that.current);
                that.current++;
            }
        }
        setInterval(increase,1000);
    }
}
var clock = new Clock(1);
clock.start();
```